# load all screen sessions in split screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I had 3 sessions open while using screen in split screen mode `-I` thought that using `CTRL + A, Q` would close the currently active split screen session, instead (i think) it just backgrounded all of them and left me on the one I was on.
Is there a way to load all my active sessions back into one window in different splits, if you will.

**** UPDATED ****
So, I didnt understand that a new screen split screen loads a new session in a different tty. This is why, im assuming, when I run jobs in a split screen I cannot see the other tasks running in the other split screens.
What I did was just create new split screens that are blank, opened new sessions. Im now attempting to load those old jobs back into the new split screens but cant see them by running jobs.
I have used `ps -fu username` ... but it only shows the process as screen

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

What I ended up doing was just resplit the screen and listed all active sessions within screen, and then loaded those

CTRL + A, "

problem solved